Android Compose semicircle arc clip
I'm looking to clip the top of a Column in a semi-circle arc shape like this:

I want the Column to be the whitespace illustrated here which will contain center-aligned Texts. The Column will lie on top of an Image. I started down a path of playing with Modifier.drawBehind containing a rect and circle with BlendModes, but I had some difficulties rendering those shapes. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Hi I have used custom shapes before and some thing similar to this and the code is as follows
class CustomTopArcShape(
    private val offsetFromTop: Dp = 50.dp
) : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val height = size.height
        val width = size.width
        val offset = with(density) { offsetFromTop.toPx() }
        
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(0f, height)
            lineTo(width, height)
            lineTo(width, 0f+offset)
            quadraticTo(width*0.5f, 0f, 0f, 0f+offset)
            lineTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(0f, height)
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }

}

this will get us a shape which looks like

then use it to clip any composable like this
Card(
  modifier = modifier.height(70.dp),
  shape = CustomTopArcShape(),
  colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor =MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background.increaseValue(0.5f))
) {

}

similarly in my use case I want to have a custom bottom Bar which should look

so I made a custom shape similar to the above code and got my final output 
Hope my answer helped you in any way, have a good day.

Hey Trinadh! I like the path you took here. ;) I think something like this would work, tweaking the Bézier curve a bit to get a more pronounced arc.

I ended up landing on this approach, drawing a circle behind the Column:
// Inside a Box with an Image background
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = surfaceTopOuterPadding)
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        .drawBehind {
            // The circle's diameter is 1.5x the width of the screen
            val radiusCoefficient = 0.75f
            drawCircle(
                color = surfaceBackgroundColor,
                radius = screenWidth * radiusCoefficient,
                center = Offset(
                    x = size.width / 2,
                    y = screenWidth * (1f - radiusCoefficient) + surfaceOuterTopPadding.toPx(),
                ),
            )
        },
) {
    // Texts
}

